# POST request not working for Django form and Django formset

Tags: django, post, django-forms, formset

I have a form, ApplyJobForm and a Formset, ApplyJobFormset. GET method works when I pass the form and the formset to a view, but for the post request the form and the formset `is_valid()` isn't working, after clicking submit it returns me to a view without saving. I am unable to save the form with the formset, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. 
Here are my codes.

models.py

```
class Applicants(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applicants')
    experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    degree = models.CharField(choices=DEGREE_TYPE, blank=True, max_length=10)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.get_full_name()} Applied'


class Certification(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicants, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applicant_certifications')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    certification = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.get_full_name()} certificate'
```

forms.py

```
class ApplyJobForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Applicants
        fields = ('job', 'degree', 'experience', 'cv')
        exclude = ('job',)
        labels = {
            'degree': 'Degree',
            'experience': 'Experience',
            'cv': 'CV',
        }
        widgets = {
            'degree': forms.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
            }
            ),
            'experience': forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
            'cv': forms.FileInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                }
            ),
        }


ApplyFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Certification,
    fields=('name', 'certification'),
    extra=1,
    widgets={
        'name': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Certification name'
            }
        ),
        'certification': forms.FileInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Upload certification'
            }
        )
    }
)
```

views.py

```
def job_apply(request, job_id=None):
    template_name = 'apply_form.html'
    applyform = ApplyJobForm(request.GET or None)
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, id=job_id)
    formset = ApplyFormset(queryset=Certification.objects.none())
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {'applyform': applyform, 'formset': formset}
        return render(request, template_name, context)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        applyform = ApplyJobForm(request.POST)
        formset = ApplyFormset(request.POST)
        if applyform.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            apply = applyform.save(commit=False)
            applyform.job = job
            apply.save()
            for form in formset:
                # so that `apply` instance can be attached.
                certification = form.save(commit=False)
                certification.apply = apply
                certification.save()
            return redirect('successful-apply')
        else:
            return redirect('job-detail', id=job.id)

    return render(request, template_name, {'applyform': applyform, 'formset': formset})
```

Here an applicant can add as many certification field when applying for a job, although the certification field is not a required field. Certification model is bound to the Applicants model.

.html

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" autocomplete="off">
.................
</form>
```

Comment: In your `job_apply` view, if the forms are not valid (`else:` case), you **should not redirect** but just render your template with the forms again (and in your template hopefully you're displaying the form errors). So remove `else: return redirect(...)` entirely, that way it'll go to the `return render(..)` line.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **never** redirect if your forms are not valid. You want to render your template with the invalid form so that you can **display** the errors to the user. This also helps debugging since you'll see the errors.

So in your view, remove these two lines:

```
        else:
            return redirect('job-detail', id=job.id)
```

so that the invalid case renders the forms in your template.

Next, since you have files to upload, you need to initialise forms that require files with `request.FILES`:

```
formset = ApplyFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

(and the same for `applyform`).

Finally make sure that in your template you are also displaying all the errors, either on each field (`{{ form.<field>.errors }}`) or globally (`{{ form.errors }}`).

Comment: Okay so I removed the two lines, added the request.FILES and tried it again. Now I get a `NOT NULL constraint failed: nueoffshore_applicants.job_id` error.

Comment: because you never assign `job` to the instance of the form (`apply`). You do `applyform.job = job` but that's useless (the form doesn't' have an attribute `job` so you're just defining it here and you're saving `apply` anyway). Look at the `save(commit=False)` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) where there's an example on how to correctly assign values to the instance.

Comment: Thanks I was able to get it to work. I did `apply.job = job` and then `certification.applicant = apply`. It was able to submit

Comment: When I tap submit, the form doesn't post, it just refresh the page and clears what I wrote in the form.

Comment: "the form doesn't post": you need to check what's really happening. Do you see a POST request being sent to your backend? Then, if that's the case, you need to use your debugger. Set a breakpoint in your view and check the flow step by step to understand why your view is returning the empty form.